# selecting lines with sed

Tags: regex, replace

I'm trying to match replace a multiple lines block with sed and I can't figure it out ..

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql',     'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'testblah',                      # Or path to database file if using     sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used     with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used     with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

I think the easiest way to do it would be something like this;

```
sed -i "s/^DATABASES\s?+=\s?+{$+8/test/" settings.py
```

In short I want to find the `DATABASES = {` include the 8 following lines in the capture and replace that with something else.

Any ideas of what's wrong ?

Comment: I think the problem is that you're not bringing in all of the lines in the match, but it's been a while. By default, the sed pattern is only run on a single line at a time, you have to do some stuff to bring in the next line using some other commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions aren't powerful enough to accurately match pairs of braces. You would need a context free grammar for that. Here is the closest to what you're original question was asking that sed can do:

Replace line starting with `DATABASES` and 9 following lines with `test`

```
sed -n -e '/^DATABASES/i test' -e '/^DATABASES/{n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;};p' settings.py
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat > f.sed
/^DATABASES/,/^}/c\ 
\
A block of replacement\
...text.
$ sed -f f.sed test.txt
```

Update: In general one should look at SO answers as directions to take rather than finished recipes. As Brian points out, details in the regular expressions will affect how general and how specific the answer is. You may well wish to make any given suggestion more of one or the other w.r.t. any pattern class...

Comment: The problem with this is that it assumes that there won't be any other '}' in the file after the end of the DATABASE JSON string. For example, duplicate the input twice and change the second DATABASES to FOO. It will replace both.

Comment: I missed the `^` before the `}`. This only works if the last curly brace (and only the last curly brace) is at the beginning of the line. This is fine if the text is well-formed. I will remove my down vote.
EDIT: odd, it doesn't seem to want to let me undo my vote.

Comment: @Brian, eh, don't worry, I've got lots of points. Stackoverflow is lucky to have people like you carefully analyzing the growing database. (I will edit the question, though, which will solve the retraction timelock.)

Comment: Sorry if I removed the accepted answer, although it worked, it did not do exactly what I wanted to do.. which was specifying the number of lines. For that I had to give it to Brian Clements. Good job guys ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you're not forced to use sed, grep -A 8 'your regexp' might work. (GNU grep)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably more easily solved in perl than in sed.  For one thing, it’s trivial to do multiline matches.

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/foo.*?bar/glarch/sg'
```

But for another, you can actually do recursive matching with nested brackets, which I fear you may need here.

Also, since perl uses EREs and sed uses BREs, you will have an easier time at it since you won’t need so many backslashes.

Also, all the `\s+` type things are supported.

Also, if this is UTF-8 text, you will still be fine; just add a `-CSD` type command-line flag.

Also, there is a sed-to-perl translator called s2p, so you know that it’s a proper superset.

Gosh, that’s sure a lot of *also* s. ☺